# My recursive function isn't returning anything

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to select a the parent form element of an input. The form element isn't necessarily the direct parent node. Currently this outputs "undefined" to my log.

```
var anInputElement = document.querySelector(...);
var formElement = getFormElement(anInputElement);
console.log(formElement);

function getFormElement(elem) {
  //if we've traversed as high as the `body` node then
  //we aint finding the `form` node
  if(elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'body') {
    var parent = elem.parentNode;
    if(parent.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'form') {
      return parent;
    } else {
      getFormElement(parent);
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Why am I getting undefined in my console log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not just

`getFormElement(parent);`

but

`return getFormElement(parent);`

and simplified, just for fun:

```
function getFormElement(elem) {
  if(elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'body') {
    var parent = elem.parentNode;
    return parent.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'form' ? parent : getFormElement(parent);
  }

  return false;
}
```